# I want to know what is in unknown [WARNING: Unknown codec unknown]

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04

I want to new music_bot in my discord.ch
so I found google cloud platform and Just-some-bot in git hub (https://github.com/Just-Some-Bots/MusicBot)
I did just fallow to step ubuntu 16.04 in this site (https://just-some-bots.github.io/MusicBot/installing/ubuntu/)

and I got a problem

There was no problem running the bot, but An error occurred when I entered a command to download YouTube. [!play url]
WARNING: Unknown codec unknown

So I searched for 3 hours for WARNING: Unknown codec unknown
I couldn't find anything like that.

I've tried to youtube-dl -U, FFMPEG update, change the locations, make another one, I've changed all the progress codes so that I can see them. [in musicbot's options], change the ubuntu 18.04 [and got the same problem]

```
> WARNING: Unknown codec unknown WARNING: Unknown codec unknown WARNING:
> Unknown codec unknown WARNING: Unknown codec unknown WARNING: Unknown
> codec unknown WARNING: Unknown codec unknown WARNING: Unknown codec
> unknown WARNING: Unknown codec unknown WARNING: Unknown codec unknown
> [FFMPEG:player][44.687691689] Data from ffmpeg: b'Output file #0 does
> not contain any stream\n' Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```